# Get post info using author id

Tags: php, wordpress

I assigned the post to author.  How to get the post info using the author id?

Is there any possibility in wordpress?

Comment: can u show what have you tried or code

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not correct. A particular author have more than 1 posts. So by giving an author id you will not get a particular post's info. Thats not practical.

Instead of that by giving author's id you can list all the posts by that author. For that use the below code:

```
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
```

Cheers!!!